# How to run a while loop just once even when the condition stays true for more time than required to complete the loop

Tags: c#, methods, while-loop

I have a application where I'm checking if the signal read from a PLC is true or false, if its true - it does a set of calculations and if its false, it waits for the signal. I'm using a while loop to do this. But the problem is that the true state stays on for 1000ms, and the loop completes in less than 100ms, so it goes back up again and since the state is true it proesses it again. Hence for 1 signal that I receive from PLC, the loop runs for about 9-10 times. I tried adding thread.sleep but still it processes it more than once. I want the loop to run once when the state is true and then wait for it to get true again.

Here is the code:

```
 bool isRunning = true;

    private void WorkThreadFunction()
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {

             if (ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Read("B3:254/1") == "True")
            {

                stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                int isTriggered;

                Int32.TryParse(trigger, out isTriggered);

                timer1.Start();


                Thread.Sleep(10);
                serialcheck();

                System.GC.Collect();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to detect the change by storing and comparing.

Comment: Then you do not use loop, you use event for such behavior.

Comment: I tried moving the whole if statement within a timer as well. Same thing happens. Can you please give a sample code of your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on a program reading signal from GPIO pin and your problem is quite similar to mine, aka preventing a single on signal from being processed multiple times. My solution to this is I try to ensure that the signal is off first before I go to check whether the signal is on again.

```
while (isRunning)
{
    var signal = ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Read("B3:254/1");
    if (signal == "True")
    {
        //do your stuff
    }

    while (signal == "True")
        signal = ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Read("B3:254/1");
}
```

The inner loop will wait for the signal to turn something other than `"True"` before it continues any other execution.

Comment: Hi,I tried your suggestion, but the application just freezes when the loop is run.

Comment: If there are other parts in your program, you probably should do it in a thread.

Comment: Hi, I created a thread to process this. It works well now, except for a small new issue. The first time the signal state is true.. it does not do anything. From the second signal onwards it starts working. Due to this, the result of the first signal turns out to be a false positive.

Comment: You should probably run a debugger to see whether you actually receive a true signal on the first true signal. The inner loop will only runs iff the signal has turn into true, without the loop, it is the same as your old code.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading it correctly you just need to put a `break;` in where your condition is met in the while loop.

I made an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FsGryD

I would also add that you might consider if using `SpinWait.SpinUntil(<boolean_condition>)` might be a better option. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait(v=vs.110).aspx).

I have used that previously on multi threading / IO waiting functions to wait for signals from devices.

Answer (score 0):

In order to wait for it to be true *again* you need to keep track of whether it has been false.

```
bool isRunning = true;
bool signalHasBeenFalse = true;

private void WorkThreadFunction()
{
    while (isRunning)
    {

         if (ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Read("B3:254/1") == "True" && hasBeenFalse )
        {
            signalHasBeenFalse = false;

            stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            int isTriggered;

            Int32.TryParse(trigger, out isTriggered);

            timer1.Start();


            Thread.Sleep(10);
            serialcheck();

            System.GC.Collect();

        }

        if ( ethernetIPforSLCMicroCom1.Read("B3:254/1") != "True" ) 
        {
            signalHasBeenFalse = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion. However, just like @lamandy's suggestion, It works, except for a small new issue. The first time the signal state is true.. it does not do anything. From the second signal onwards it starts working. Due to this, the result of the first signal turns out to be a false positive